# Конвертирование gif в webm и mp4 с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, gif

Стоит задача конвертировать gif в 2 видео формата. С webm проблем нет, применяю

```
$ ffmpeg -f gif -i in.gif out.webm
```

Всё прекрасно обрабатывается и работает в браузерах. Применяю аналогичное для mp4

```
$ ffmpeg -f gif -i in.gif out.mp4
```

Ошибок нет, видео без проблем сохраняется, но при этом **mp4 отказывается проигрываться в любом браузере кроме хрома. В чём может быть проблема?**

Другие браузеры поддерживают mp4, оно прекрасно работает на других сайтах, а у меня нет. Если скачать видео и запустить через любую из программ для просмотра, то просто чёрный экран на всё время видеоролика.

**UPD**

Попробовал кучу других способов, в том числе советы с англоязычного SO, не работает везде кроме хрома. Что за тайные технологии использует хром?)

[Вот что пишет в консоли, когда конвертирую](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/?url=ya-disk-public%3A%2F%2FceZuL%2F4NbwZo7%2F5BNTBTHU8WEWyEpISraHPXgwud2c0%3D&name=log.txt&c=551e6fa89fd4)

[Файл 1.gif](https://yadi.sk/i/9v3bl8mUfirzn)

[Файл 2.gif после конвертирования](https://yadi.sk/i/MlZVkSNVfirzk), яндекс преобразует его во флеш или делает что-то с ним и он начинает работать во всех браузерах :(

А если просто я открою путь до файла на сайте после конвертирования, то будет(в опере):

[скрин](https://leto49f.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/fb6b52138de6d43f791d1153553a818df765b7c3790affc0f8aa955166ac3541/inf/ta5jqZ-VcDlJ0aGMzB3o1uxSFLskLj5vwgbS1hLI8ftt0237-qzRiesgL9rvXYAD30Pwn5mnAiKbNvgVfv6YnQ==?uid=0&filename=2.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&tknv=v2&rtoken=7d62002d86c7f5a893f3e3c686ed61d9&force_default=no)

В хроме видео работает, в лисице "видео не может быть воспроизведено, так как файл повреждён...

Вот ссылка на файл 2.mp4, который получается после обработки(не преобразованный):

[ссылка](http://dropmefiles.com/CXZQd)

В любой программе, он открывается как чёрный экран.

**UPD**

Я бы грешил на браузеры или кодеки, если бы файлы: сайт/файл.mp4 не открывались на других сайтах(без флеша, просто объект video, где в source указан путь до mp4, что делаю и я), а они открываются....

**UPD**

9 час борьбы с mp4, ничего не помогает. Неужели никто не сталкивался с такой или подобной задачей?

Answer (score 1):

Некропост, но всё же.

Я попробовал сделать из вашего 1.gif mp4 при помощи второй команды: файл нормально открылся в Firefox (45.0), ffmpeg - 3.0.

Второе, указать `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, как рекомендует сам ffmpeg. Но тут беда: используемый по дефолту кодек h264 умеет работать с разрешениями кратными двум. У вас же - 477 ширина. Решение: кропнуть изображение на 1 пиксель:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf crop=476 out.mp4
```

Кроме того, стоит попробовать использовать другие кодеки:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -c:v mpeg2video out.mp4
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -c:v mpeg4 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
ffmpeg -i in.gif -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```